# create and loop through arrays of folders in shell

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, zsh

Please feel free to rename the question to something more appropriate.

How would I mimic the below `zsh` using `bash` instead?

```
mkdir folder1
mkdir folder2
mkdir folder3

# zsh

folders=(folder*) | print $folders
#folder1 folder2 folder3

# bash

folders=(folder*/) | echo $folders
#folder1
```

As you can see, this only outputs the first element.

Any pointers would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are your folders in the same directory ?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Yes they are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing it to:

```
folders=(folder*); echo "${folders[@]}"
```

- `folders[@]` gives all the elements in the array
- `${}` expands the output from above command to bash.

Comment: @jO It works if you separate the echo to a different line, or if you add a semicolon between the commands instead of a pipe.

Comment: This works as-is for me.  Just copy and paste.  @jO, your use of the pipe operator is incorrect in bash, it is probably part of your problem.  This answer correctly uses semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

If lets say, you  have multiple .txt file  in some Directory and you want to get/display those folders . you can try something like this:

```
declare -a folder_arr
i=0


for dir in *.txt; do

folder_arr[i]=$dir
i=$((i+1))
done

for j in $(seq 0 $((i-1)))
do
echo ${folder_arr[$j]}
done
```

I excuted the above file and was able to get the expected reult.

```
   /temps$ ./dirrr.sh
    z.txt
```

Comment: Do not iterate over the output of `find` like this. See [this bash pitfall](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) for details.

Comment: Hey @chepner Thanks for the feedback. You are right....I didnt have access to a linux machine earlier to try it...but, know I do.  I have fixed it as per the  "this bash pitfall"  and now it work fine..... TAKE A BOW  :)